# macOS server Xcode bots aren't visible in browser, but are visible in Xcode report navigator

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server

I'm having an issue with Xcode 8.2 and Server 5.2: The bots in my report navigator are present and integrations are working as expected, but the same bots aren't accessible from the {server_ip}/xcode interface.

[image]
(not actual bots: taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/view_integration_results.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH4-SW1) for demonstration purposes)

They show up in the Xcode report, but not the web interface:
[image]

However, when I use the "view bot in browser" feature, the bot appears to begin loading but never completes:
[image]

The builds are manually signed integration logs are visible for each bot:
[image]

My question is: how can I debug the bots not showing up in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed run a `sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset` and rebuild my bots from scratch. **Warning**: running `sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset` will remove *all* of you bots.